# avoid pytest executing python script code during collection

Tags: pytest

I have it in my project that every python file that has executable python code directly in it, i.e. code that is not encapsulated in a class, *will be [executed by pytest while pytest is collecting](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions/9922)*. How can this be avoided?

If I add this at the top of the source file, then the file won't be collected, but then it can also not be run outside of pytest (because the skip raises a pytest `Skipped` exception)

```
import pytest
pytest.skip(allow_module_level=True)
```

Comment: Can't you just use the usual `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard?

Comment: When run with regular python, the pytest.skip from above will throw and the interpreter will never get to the `if __name__` clause.

Comment: By why do you need that `pytest.skip` in the first place, if you use `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

Comment: Because pytest loads the entire module regardless of that line. By the time it gets to that line it has already loaded (initialized) the module. Or I'm missing how that clause can avoid the initialization of the module.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by module initialization. I assumed that you meant  the execution of global functions, which can be moved behind the guard. If you are meaning the import of modules, this would be another matter.